# How to get the command that invoked a task with tasklist?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, task-manager

The Windows task manager has a column labeled **Command Line** that shows the command that started the given task, with all the switches and parameters, for example:

```
test.exe -V -A 127.0.0.1 -P 6062
```

Now I have to identify a certain task that is listening on a certain port and/or was called with a certain switch combination. My aim is to close the selected task, but not others, so if there are multiple `test.exe` tasks running, I cannot simply close all tasks returned by:

```
tasklist /fo csv /nh /fi "imagename eq test.exe"
```

Unfortunately it seems like neither `tasklist` nor `pslist` ([here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx)) is able to return the **Command Line** field. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Maybe you can do something with `netstat -aon | grep \.0:6062` for port 6062 and the last column would be the PID of your program. Not sure if that sufficient for you. `tasklist /FI "PID eq <PID>"` would give your executable again.

Comment: @Rik Sadly, that is not sufficient, as the port itself is not enough to identify the correct task, so it is necessary to see the command line arguments too.

Comment: Can't imagine multiple programs listening on the same port... :) But it must be possible to get the parameters... `process explorer` from Sysinternals can show these in the gui. So the info must be somewhere.

Comment: Do you have use for a powershell command? Like <<< Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "name like '%test.exe'"|select CreationDate,ProcessId,CommandLine|ft -AutoSize` >>> See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494073/commandline-arguments-of-running-process-in-dos)

Comment: @Rik, the port is of course different, but I have to extract the command line arguments also to check whether the task is the one I need to kill.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

How about this one:

```
wmic process where caption="test.exe" get commandline
```

And if you do this you also get the ProcessId to kill:

```
wmic process where caption="test.exe" get commandline,processid
```

`wmic` also has a switch to output to csv. So:

```
wmic /output:c:\temp\proc.csv process where caption="test.exe" get commandline,processid /format:csv
```

Note: If you get an error with the last one (`Invalid XSL format (or) file name`) you need to copy `csv.xml` from `%WINDIR%\System32\wbem\en-US` to `%WINDIR%\System32\wbem`. You can read about this bug [here](http://acidx.net/wordpress/2012/09/retrieving-system-information-via-command-line-on-windows/).

---

You could also use PowerShell:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "name like '%test.exe'"|select CreationDate,ProcessId,CommandLine|ft -AutoSize`
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it, `wmic` solves the problem, and this concludes the day. :)

Comment: Perfect - this actually gives the full command line. In task manager, it only shows the first 300 characters or so.

Comment: why wmic returns empty commandlines for svchost.exe ?

Comment: @FlashThunder Because svchost.exe isn't started with commandlines. It gets it's commands another way and each svchost can process several services (not just one). What is the information you want from that process? For instance you can see the services with `tasklist /svc`.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell 7:

```
get-process test | % commandline
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11, at least, the top answer above did not work, as there is no "caption" column in `wmic process` output, so there was no result found. (And yes, I realize wmic is deprecated in Windows 11. It DOES still work.)

Instead, there are indeed other columns you could use for that WHERE clause, and they're available with wmic `process list /?`. Among those are of course `name` (for the process name)--and that `processid` (for the pid) mentioned above, so this worked for me instead:

`wmic process where name="test.exe" get commandline,processid`

One more thing: **I found I had to be running an elevated command prompt (as admin) to see the commandline**. Otherwise the ouput showed the commandline as empty:

```
CommandLine  ProcessId
             10496
```